# Update Custom Slider on Settings Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm creating a custom slider element for the WPBakery Page Builder plugin, as the built in carousels are not suitable for my purpose.

Everything works just fine except when I update the element settings, the slider disappears because the element is re-created in the DOM by removing the old HTML.

Here's the element code:

```
<?php
class WPBakery_Custom_Slider {
    /**
     * Setup class
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Actions.
        add_action( 'vc_before_init', array( $this, 'custom_mapping' ) );

        // Shortcodes.
        add_shortcode( 'wpbakery_custom_slider', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Custom Mapping
     */
    public function custom_mapping() {
        vc_map( array(
            'name'             => __( 'Custom Slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'base'             => 'wpbakery_custom_slider',
            'description'      => __( 'The Custom Slider.', 'text-domain' ),
            'category'         => __( 'Content', 'text-domain' ),
            'icon'             => 'icon-wpb-carousel',
            'front_enqueue_js' => get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/wpbakery-page-builder.js' ),
            'params'           => array(
                ...
            ),
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * The element HTML
     *
     * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes.
     * @return string
     */
    public function shortcode( $atts ) {
        // Params extraction.
        ...

        ob_start();
        ?>

        <div class="text-domain-wpb-custom-slider-wrapper">
            <div class="text-domain-wpb-custom-slider">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $html = ob_get_clean();

        return $html;
    }
}
```

And here's the `wpbakery-page-builder.js` file:

```
vc.events.on( 'shortcodes:wpbakery_custom_slider:update', function ( model ) {
    jQuery( document ).find( '.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider' ).customSlider();
} );
```

But when the event runs, it seems like the `.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider` does not exist. The variants I tried are:

```
vc.events.on( 'shortcodes:wpbakery_custom_slider:update', function ( model ) {
    jQuery( '.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider', document ).customSlider();
} );
```

And

```
vc.events.on( 'shortcodes:wpbakery_custom_slider:update', function ( model ) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        jQuery( '.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider', document ).customSlider();
    }, 1000 );
} );
```

All the above, when saving the settings of the element results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).customSlider is not a function
```

Because `jQuery( '.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider', document ).length` is zero even though there's a `.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider` in the DOM.

Any ideas of how to properly update a custom JavaScript-based element for WPBakery Page Builder/Visual Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the `document` variable. It refers to the Builder edit page, not the page that needs to be edited (called `model` by WPBakery).

So here's the solution, use `model.view.el` instead of `document` to refer to the page:

```
vc.events.on( 'shortcodes:wpbakery_custom_slider:update', function ( model ) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        jQuery( model.view.el ).find( '.text-domain-wpb-custom-slider' ).customSlider();
    }, 1000 );
} );
```